# Firefox MediaKeys input JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to write an addon that lets me use my media keys with spotify web. The key input should work even if the Firefox window isn't selected. Right now I'm using this code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.key == "MediaTrackNext"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-skip-forward-16")[0].click();
    }else if(event.key == "MediaTrackPrevious"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-skip-back-16")[0].click();
    }else if(event.key == "MediaPlayPause"){
        if(document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-pause-16 control-button--circled").length == 0){
            document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-play-16 control-button--circled")[0].click();
        }else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("control-button spoticon-pause-16 control-button--circled")[0].click();
        }
    }
});
```

But if the spotify tab isn't selected or the Firefox window isn't selected it doesn't work.

How could I get the media keys to work?